# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Tags: python, date, arcpy, strftime

I have the code below :

```
import arcpy, os

from arcpy.sa import *


arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

fc = r'E:\dada proj\DRAW OBJECTS\VIPPoints.mdb\Allfeat'
# Point feature class, needs to be in a file geodatabase (for the where clause to work)
output_folder = r'C:\GIS\data\testdata'  # Where the rasters will be saved

date_field = 'date_'  # field holding the dates (date type, not string)
value_fields = ['CO', 'O3', 'NO2']  # field with the values to interpolate

all_dates = list({i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, date_field)})  # List all unique dates



for date in all_dates:
    # Create a feature layer of each unique date
    where = "{0}=date '{1}'".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=fc, field=date_field),
                                    date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=fc, out_layer='lyr', where_clause=where)

    # For each field interpolate. This is untested since I dont have spatial analyst
    for fieldname in value_fields:
        outIDW = Idw(in_point_features='lyr', z_field=fieldname,
                     cell_size=10)  # , {power}, {search_radius}, {in_barrier_polyline_features})
        outIDW.save(os.path.join(output_folder, '{0}_{1}.tif'.format(fieldname, date.strftime('%Y%m%d'))))
```

while I run it I get error

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

my date are in table and format : yyyy/mm/dd
thanks for any suggestion to solve error

Comment: Apparently you are using `.strftime` as a method on a string where you expect to have something else.

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: `strftime` is a `datatime.datetime` (and `datatime.date`) method, but not one of a unicode string — so apparental that's what in the you `all_dates` list.